# Huge json object to excel?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have a PHP application which has a table with more then 10000 rows and I am trying to export that into an excel sheet via my ROR application but my request is getting timed out on the server by PHP application.So I was wondering is there any elegant way to solve this problem. I come up with 2 solutions. First is doing a batch processing (need to read about as I am new with it) and the other is that my php application will send a large json object and my ruby app will read that json object write the data to excel sheet and sends back the excel sheet.So I wanted to ask whether is there any better way to deal with this problem ? And how can I convert json to excel I did google and did found excel to json but not vice versa. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the layout of your data, can you post the first 5 important lines? Maybe one can exploit the layout to create a .csv, if this would be enough.

Comment: The data will be a record from a table. This is a row from a CSV file 8630,"19190","qwer","144","xyz",NULL,"3","2","3","0",,"16",‌​"0","0","0","101","16","415~20130404094900~5.00","0","0.00","5.00","0.00","5.00",‌​"0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","5.00","5.00",NULL,NULL,,‌​"11~5",,,,"2~5","11~5","38~5",,,,,,,"38~5""

Comment: What is your json object?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - my json object is a set of records from the db table.

Comment: I am not a real expert in this field but I think it would help me if I saw the objects, specs what shall  be converted to what and how you do excel to json, what your data looks like and generally what you want to achieve. If you did not find a solution with google we may need to construct an own solution.

Comment: Json is an representation format for objects. If you say 'json object', I think you mean you have an object that shall be converted to a string by calling something like `y = xxx.to_json` and what comes out is the json object in `y`.

Comment: I have a dump json file from phpmyadmin .It comes when you do export data.It looks like [{"id": 1,"pro_id": 3,"pro_name": "asdf","cli_id": 113,"cli_name": "tyuryt",... (and so on)

Answer (score 1):

I had some time so I constructed a json to excel csv converter in ruby1.9:

It reads from one file an writes it into an other file.

`json2excel.rb`

```
def json2excel(fromFile, toFile)
  pos = 0
  while true
    c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
    if c == ' ' or c == "\n" or c == "\r"
      # whitespace
    elsif c == '['
      # first bracket begins!
      attributes = []
      while true
        c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
        if c == '{'
          # now an object starts
          object = Hash.new
          while true
            puts "!!!"
            c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
            if c == '"'
              # new attribute starts
              name = ""
              while true
                c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                if c == '"'
                  break
                else
                  name += c
                end
              end
              attributes << name unless attributes.include? name
              # scan for :
              while true
                c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                if c == ':'
                  break
                elsif  c == ' ' or c == '\n' or c == '\r' # whitespace is ok
                else raise "4malformed json for excel conversion! char: #{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
                end
              end
              # scan for staring value
              while true
                c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                if c == '"'
                  # string follows
                  value = ""
                  value << c
                  while true
                    c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                    value << c
                    if c == '"'
                      break
                    end
                  end
                  c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                  break
                elsif  c == ' ' or c == '\n' or c == '\r' # whitespace is ok
                elsif "1234567890".include? c
                  # number follows
                  value = ""
                  value << c
                  while true
                    c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                    if "1234567890".include? c
                      value << c
                    else break
                    end
                  end
                  break
                elsif c == "t"
                  # true follows
                  c = fromFile.read(3);pos += 3
                  if c != "rue"
                    raise "excpected true but found t#{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
                  end
                  value = "true"
                  c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                  break
                elsif c == "f"
                  # false follows
                  c = fromFile.read(4);pos += 4
                  if c != "alse"
                    raise "excpected false but found f#{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
                  end
                  value = "false"
                  c = fromFile.read(1);pos += 1
                  break
                else raise "5malformed json for excel conversion! char: #{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
                end
              end
              # value starts
              object[name] = value
              puts object
            end
            puts "c: #{c.inspect}"
            if c == "," 
              # comma is ok! just take many of them, does not hurt.
            elsif  c == ' ' or c == '\n' or c == '\r'
              # whitespace is ok
            elsif c == "}"
              # object ends!
              break
            else raise "3malformed json for excel conversion! char: #{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
            end
          end
          attributes.each{|attr|
            value = object[attr]
            raise "expected object #{object} to have attribute #{attr} position: #{pos}" if value.nil?
            toFile.write(value)
            toFile.write(',')
          }
          toFile.write("\"\"\r\n") # this is the csv new line. a new object begins here
        elsif  c == ' ' or c == '\n' or c == '\r'
          # whitespace is ok
        elsif c == ']'
          attributes.each{ |attr|
            toFile.write(attr.inspect)
            toFile.write(",")
          }
          toFile.write("\"\"\r\n") # this is the csv new line. a new object begins here
          # the end of the file
          c = fromFile.read()
          if c != ''
            raise "end of listing was reached. skipping #{c.size} character after position #{pos}: #{c.inspect}"
          end
          break
        elsif c == ','
          # comma is ok! just take many of them, does not hurt.
        else
          raise "2malformed json for excel conversion! char: #{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
        end
      end
      break
    else
      raise "1malformed json for excel conversion! char: #{c.inspect} position: #{pos}"
    end
  end
end

json2excel(File.open('json.txt'), File.open('excel.csv', 'wb'))
```

`json.txt`

```
[{"id": 1,"pro_id": 3,"pro_name": "asdf","cli_id": 113,"cli_name": "tyuryt"} , {"id": 1,"pro_id": 3,"pro_name": "asdf","cli_id": 113,"cli_name": "tyuryt"}]
```

`excel.csv`

```
1,3,"asdf",113,"tyuryt",""
1,3,"asdf",113,"tyuryt",""
"id","pro_id","pro_name","cli_id","cli_name",""
```

your column names are in the end of the file.

if new attributes are introduced after the first object not all columns will be of equal element count.

Note: it does not load everything into memory but writes it to the file as soon as possible.

What it does not do:

- negative numbers
- numbers with a `.` in them
- strings with `"` in it.