# Can't access Mysql model in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

I have an existing remote mysql database and I am trying to access that from my rails application I have this in my database.yml
development:

```
 development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  username: myusername
  password: !@#$%@!
  host: IP for my DB
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock  
  timeout: 5000
```

when I run the following the command in my rails console

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

It list all the available tables but when I try to access the model it gives me the following error:

```
City
NameError: uninitialized constant City from (irb):12
    from /home/shreyas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/shreyas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/shreyas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong ? I want to access the remote database in my application I havent created any models as of now. Do I need to create all the models? I can see the complete db structure in my schema.rb file.

Comment: That doesn't look like a mysql error, show your models

Comment: This is not an mysql error when I try to access the tables of my DB . Like City is the table name so when I try to access city.first or anything it shows me the above error.

Comment: Can I see your City model

Comment: Its a remote database. I haven't created it.

Comment: it would be better, if you can share your City model (app/models/city.rb)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the database is stored, you need a model..

Comment: I can see this in my schema.rb create_table "city", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "name",      :limit => 100, :null => false
    t.string  "abbr_name", :limit => 100, :null => false
    t.integer "test",                     :null => false

  end

Comment: @BachanSmruty I havent created any models? Do i need to create one and if yes then how should I do this? I have table structure in my schema.rb file.

Comment: For that in console you can write the code like
rails g model City

it will create the City model for you. As you said, you have existing table, so you don't need the migration generated by the above syntax. So you should delete the generated migration from db/migrate.

Comment: I have created one model named city but still didn't got any success. So my problem definition is I have an existing database and I want to access that in my application. How to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that in console you can write the code like

```
rails g model City
```

it will create the City model for you. As you said, you have existing table, so you don't need the migration generated by the above syntax. So you should delete the generated migration from db/migrate.

OR else you can do one thing just add city.rb file in the app/models. Then add the code

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   # if your table name is cities, then you don't need to do any thing.
   # if your table name is something else rather than cities then place the following commented code
   # self.table_name = 'your_existing_city_table_name'

   # then you have to add columns of the table as attr_accessible. for e.g. you have name, state_id in there
   attr_accessible :name, :state_id
end
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: @BachanSmuthy I did follow the steps the name of the table in my db is is city(small case) but when I try to access City it says City(Table doesn't exist) and if I use city it gives me the same error. :(

Comment: Have you added self.table_name = 'city' in the City model?

Comment: You can upvote the question if you dont mind ;) and I have one more question in my que if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185439/huge-json-object-to-excel

Comment: How stupid I am how can I forget this. Thanks mate thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, make sure to double check your models. I created them manually and forgot to allow Active Record to be aware of my models.

I had:

```
class Currency
  ...
end
```

you need to change this to show

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

Might save you hours of debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

You can of course access your data inside your `mysql` database but in order to use it as an object representation you need to create a `model` associated with your data.

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This way `ActiveRecord` will do the hard work for you in order to "link" your object to the data in your database (assuming the models name are correct, here you should have a table named `cities`).

You will then be able to fetch cities from rails console

```
City.all
```

For more informations on ActiveRecord, please refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: So how can I add the existing Models in my application. I dont have migrations but I can see all the table structure in my schema.rb file. And by mistake I have already cleared the database by running rake db:schema:load

Comment: not sure to understand. If you already have your database filled up with data, simply add ruby classes (create the files and paste the code) like I showed above in order to be able to access your data through ruby and active record. However, not having migrations will probably be an issue for you at some point. For example when pushing your code on your production server...